# VLC cannot display the subtitles in the SubRip(srt) file

Tags: bash, subtitle, video-player

I've downloaded the videos and subtitles from the course [How to Use Git and Github](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud775/l-2969618657/m-2960548760) in the **Udacity** and found only the time stamps instead of the subtitles were displayed in the video player **VLC**.

It seems the format of the **Udacity**'s srt file is not supported fully by the **VLC**. So is there any method to convert these srt files' format to make them readable by the  **VLC**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking both the **SubRip**/**srt** file's format syntax from [VLC's Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/SubRip/) and the downloaded srt file's format, I found two differences:

1. The frame's No. is missing in the downloaded srt file.
2. **SubRip**'s syntax use `h1:m1:s1 --> h2:m2:s2` to define the time, but the downloaded file use `h1:m1:s1,h2:m2:s2`.

And after some testing I found the first difference is not important but the second is. So I wrote a **bash** script below to convert the format,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#convert-srt-for-udacity
srt=$1
dos2unix "$srt" 2>/dev/null
sed -ie "s/^\([[:digit:]:.]*\),\([[:digit:]:.]*\)[[:blank:]]*$/\1 --> \2/" "$srt"
```

At last use this command to convert all subtitles batchly

```
for i in *.srt; do ./convert-srt-for-udacity "$i"; done
```

Comment: As a beginner, I can't undertand how it finds the srt files. I don't see any path.

Comment: @YannisDran Please download the *Transcripts* just under the *Videos* which include those srt files.

Comment: I was asking how your bash code handles the files. I had already downloaded the transcripts with srt files.

Comment: not working. 1. in the srt folder, running above command change nothing. 2. running "./convert-srt-for-udacity test.srt" output test.srte which is exaclty the same as test.srt.

Comment: @YannisDran Suppose you download from here: `curl --header 'Host: zips.udacity-data.com' --header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0' --header 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' --header 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --header 'Connection: keep-alive' 'http://zips.udacity-data.com/2969618657/Lesson%202%20Subtitles.zip' -o 'Lesson 2 Subtitles.zip' -L`, then extranct the package and go into it, and run `for i in *.srt; do ../convert-srt-for-udacity "$i"; done`, you will find the formats have been changed.

Comment: @YannisDran And I have found not all srt files downloaded from *Udacity* are not compatiable with VLC.

Comment: Cool. Finally did it with a Bash and a Notepad++ for Windows.